# How to generate bundle.js with react and webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have started to play with react and soemhow get stucked.
I have following code: [github.com/gandra/my-lara-react-app](https://github.com/gandra/my-lara-react-app)

When I runn following code on the `command-line`:

```
npm install
webpack --config webpack.config.js
```

I expect to find file `./dist/bundle.js`  but this not happens.
Any idea why?

Comment: It would be better to include that webpack.config.js here. `wntry` in that file is probably a typo.

Comment: :) such simple solution - tipo :)
Post it as a solution I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file mentioned in the question, `webpack.config.js` contains a typo `wntry`, which should have been `entry`, i.e.

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: ['./app/main.js'],
    ...
}
```